# Who is pleased?

Tags: subjects

In the sentence, who is pleased, Malfoy or Crabbe and Goyle?

> Malfoy went to join his friends Crabbe and Goyle, looking pleased with himself.

Comment: It's Malfoy. Otherwise the sentence would be "Malfoy went to join his friends Crabbe and Goyle, ***who*** looked pleased with ***themselves***."

Comment: @PeterShor As the OP incorrectly (and unnecessarily) suspects, it could, grammatically, be Goyle. But the comma after Goyle is a give away. Listenever, what were you expecting? Crabbe? Goyle? Both? Why do you think so? Does the grammar and punctuation suggest something to you?

Comment: Generally, that's a poor style. While the comma removes the ambiguity in writing, it is lost in speech and the meaning doesn't jump at the reader, one has to spot it. It would be better rephrased with *Malfoy, looking pleased with himself, went...*

Comment: @Kris: It's not the comma. To me, a native English speaker, the sentence *"Malfoy went to join his friends Crabbe and Goyle looking pleased with themselves"* is clearly ungrammatival (with our without the comma).  I don't know why, which is why I didn't post an answer. Maybe I should have, since nobody else has explained why, either. This is a subtle English grammar point, and it isn't helping the OP if you imply that it's obvious.

Comment: Without the comma, it's an identifying clause, which is illicit because C and G are fully identified. _He went to talk to the men looking pleased with themselves_ is possible provided this means _those among the already-mentioned men present who were looking pleased with themselves_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Malfoy. Aside from the comma, *himself* can't refer to anyone else but Malfoy.

Answer (score 1):

You should observe the use of the comma which means it's Malfoy who is pleased. Without the comma, it could mean differently.

Comment: The comma ***doesn't mean anything***.  *"I found the cat, looking pleased with herself, with our Thanksgiving turkey."*

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely Malfoy who is pleased.